# Iframe url manipulation and add as query string

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, perl, iframe

I have a legacy application that runs in perl. I developed an MVC application with just one default.aspx. Inside default.aspx i put a master page and an iframe to open the legacy application url. What i want to do is everytime, the iframe tries to navigate to next page (i mean, within iframe), i want to capture the url in my default.aspx and add a querystring to the iframe's src

Example:

In legacy application, the first page is  http ://iframe.com/index.cgi. Clicking on a link in index.cgi and it goes to http: //iframe.com/product.cgi

In my MVC application, i will open "http ://iframe.com/index.cgi?MyQueryString" in iframe. When we click on the link in index.cgi, as per legacy application, it will try to move to http: //iframe.com/product.cgi. But I want to make it "http: //iframe.com/product.cgi?MyQueryString"

---

Any idea how to achieve this please?

P.S. I am not allowed to change anything in the legacy perl application. All i can do should be done in the Default.aspx only

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to do something like this:

```
<iframe id="perlIframe" src="http://yourPerlURLhere" onload="recordMe(this)"></iframe>​
```

Then you each time the `iframe` loads a new page you could grab the `src` or `location.href` sorta like this:

```
function recordMe(a){    
    console.log(a.src);
```

or

```
    console.log(a.location.href);
```

But you will end up running into some 'same origin' issues if these two pages are not on the same domain.

Comment: they are in same domain... this a.src always gives http: //yourPerlURLhere no matter where you navigate within iframe

Comment: frame.contentDocument.location.href -- this one gave the frame's url